# I Want to Print month with year in php

Tags: php, datetime

I have facing trouble to print date and month,I need to print January-2016 not Jan-2016.

I have tried `<? echo date("Y-M");?>`

Please suggest.

Answer (score 3):

Try this for full month name

```
<?php echo date("F-Y"); ?>  //January-2016
```

Comment: You are an established user Syed. Surely you know this is a duplicate? Instead of answering the question it is better to flag it as such :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this this help you

```
echo date("Y-m");
```

Answer (score 0):

For January-2006

```
echo date('F-Y');
```

For 2006-January

```
echo date("Y-F");
```

Y = year in digits

F = full month text

Comment: I think "January-2006" is what you want not "2006-January"